# Unable to properly convert a long integer to array with str_split()

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a long integer to array with `str_split()`.

```
    $input = 13216786487124;
    print_r(str_split($input));
    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 7
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 4
)
```

However, adding just another digit turns the input to exponential form and the array elements are not not what I expect.

```
    $input = 132167864871245;
    print_r(str_split($input));

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => .
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 8
    [11] => 7
    [12] => 1
    [13] => 2
    [14] => 4
    [15] => E
    [16] => +
    [17] => 1
    [18] => 4
)
```

Quoting works: `$input = "132167864871245";`

Casting does not work: `print_r(str_split((string) $input));`

Is there a way to get around by not using double quotes?

Comment: You have to. Otherwise it's an integer and if you're exceeding the integer range PHP will convert it to float. And with floats you get such things.

Comment: The real question is why you are storing such a long string of numbers as an integer/float, Are you doing math on it? If no, it should be a string. If yes, it should still be a string and you should be using BC Math.

Comment: Once the numeric string is stored as a NUMBER, it is subject to the limitations of the PHP version you are running and the machine it's running on (see: [PHP Manual: Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)).  Once that happens and an Integer Overflow occurs, the number loses digit(s).  As Chris said, store it as a string to avoid corruption.

Answer (score 0):

As Charlotte Dunois mentioned in his comment, your number is to large for integer type and it's casted to float.

But here's a solution. You can simply use `number_format` function to convert it to string first like this:

```
echo number_format($input,0,'.','');
```

Also `sprintf` can help you here:

```
echo sprintf('%.0f', $input);
```

After that you're dealing with a string so you can work with it as you've already did when you tried with defined as string (quoted value).

Comment: number_format() worked for what I was trying to do. 
Given an array of integers, I was trying to determine if they included digits 0-9.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your comment. Does my answer covers the question or is there still some problem?